# CNN or other for Tree Species Identification in Boreal

Tags: classification, conv-neural-network

Apologies if I am posting to the wrong forum.

I am currently taking a course on CNN's and deep learning and am beginning to think about how I might start applying what I have learnt to some of my current problems. The one problem that I am currently focusing on is the identification of tree species type from large scale (500km x 500km @ 15cm resolution) aerial imagery (RGB) and LiDAR point cloud datasets. Data is from the boreal forest which can typically have 4 or 5 main tree species of concern for classification. The LiDAR is relatively low quality @2-4 hits per meter^2. I have a decent sample set of plots for the area where trees have been "stem-mapped" meaning I can label tree positions and species type within these plots. I have been scouring the internet for 4 or 5 hours now, reading a few articles here and there, but am unable to draw a parallel between what I want to do and what the various papers have been doing. Reading about new methods like resnet and other has gotten me excited, but I just can't get a process in my head so I am hoping for a nudge in the right direction. Can anyone point me towards some articles or have any thoughts on how to approach this problem?

I am working with tensorflow and typcial python libraries.

UPDATE:

Seeing as though my question hasn't been kicked to the curb, I will expand on things a little to try and prime the conversation a little more.

Sid, you mention a hypothesis that for any given image I would have a probable tree species. My answer to that is difficult, lets see if I can explain it well enough. I have a massive aerial image of a forest. In that forest are hundreds of thousands, even many millions, of individual trees.[image]

I have been thinking of performing a crown identification routine to grab each tree crown. Then, theoretically, each crown could become its own image. This would make an absolutely MASSIVE dataset and I feel this method would be ridiculous. I believe that I could make a model using CNN's regarding stem counts where each image would represnt a specific amount of trees trained as per the plot data. But as for the main problem of ID'ing tree species, regarding your question Sid, I believe, is that no, in one image I will not have a predominant tree species.

So again, I ask, anything regarding theoretical methods to attack my problem and/or resources to explore would be hugely appreciated.

Further, I am particularly interested in the CNN methodology as new field plot data comes in regularly which could impact predictions. This coupled with the fact that image information changes from area to area (RGB, NIR values, LiDAR quality) really drives home, to me anyways, that CNN's are the way to go for this problem.

I have now found an article that I believe begins to address my problem. Unfortunately, as a newbie, I cannot understand the methodology section well enough to replicate. Can anyone assist in the interpretation of it?
http://www.cfs.nrcan.gc.ca/pubwarehouse/pdfs/29602.pdf

Comment: Is your hypothesis that for a given image, will there be predominantly 1 tree species?

Comment: I don't think this is too broad since David wants general pointers and articles.

Comment: Could you show us an example of the LIDAR training set? It sounds like if you have labels for each individual tree, then you're doing a pixelwise labelling, which in this case is effectively segmentation: https://vision.in.tum.de/research/image_segmentation

where each pixel can be either a particular tree-species or background.

Comment: Also keep in mind that this problem is greatly simplified by specifying geographic location priors, including altitude.

Comment: Thanks. I found http://blog.qure.ai/notes/semantic-segmentation-deep-learning-review which has given me a great sense of image segmentation. As I mentioned, I am new to this and am still in the process of learning through course work. I am unsure as to what would comprise the training set as of yet as I have access to so much data. Do you mean the raw LiDAR data within one of the field measured plots? Processed LiDAR products for the plot? Processed LiDAR and other products (imagery) I have for each plot? I am unsure of your meaning in your second comment.